# Hibernate delete child when parent is getting updated in same transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have defined two entities Customer and SalesOrder in my domain model with oneToMany relationship from customer to salesOrder.
Below code deletes the sales order:

```
SalesOrder salesOrder = salesOrderRepository.findByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
if(null != salesOrder){
        Customer customer = salesOrder.getCustomer();
        customer.setCurrentCredit(customer.getCurrentCredit() - salesOrder.getTotalPrice());
Iterator<SalesOrder> iter = customer.getSalesOrders().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            SalesOrder order = iter.next();
            if(order.getId().equals(salesOrder.getId())){
                iter.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        customerRepository.save(customer);
```

But the below code does not delete the sales order.

```
SalesOrder salesOrder = salesOrderRepository.findByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
if(null != salesOrder){
        Customer customer = salesOrder.getCustomer();
        customer.setCurrentCredit(customer.getCurrentCredit() - salesOrder.getTotalPrice());
SalesOrder salesOrder = salesOrderRepository.findByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
if(null != salesOrder){
        Customer customer = salesOrder.getCustomer();
        customer.setCurrentCredit(customer.getCurrentCredit() - salesOrder.getTotalPrice());
        salesOrderRepository.delete(salesOrder);
        customerRepository.save(customer);
```

Below are the domain classes : 
Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", uniqueConstraints = {       @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "code" }) })
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

@Column
private String code;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String address;

@Column
private String phone1;

@Column
private String phone2;

@Column
private Double creditLimit;

@Column
private Double currentCredit;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="customer",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<SalesOrder> salesOrders = new ArrayList<SalesOrder>();

/**
 * @return the code
 */
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

/**
 * @param code the code to set
 */
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the address
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

/**
 * @param address the address to set
 */
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

/**
 * @return the phone1
 */
public String getPhone1() {
    return phone1;
}

/**
 * @param phone1 the phone1 to set
 */
public void setPhone1(String phone1) {
    this.phone1 = phone1;
}

/**
 * @return the phone2
 */
public String getPhone2() {
    return phone2;
}

/**
 * @param phone2 the phone2 to set
 */
public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
    this.phone2 = phone2;
}

/**
 * @return the creditLimit
 */
public Double getCreditLimit() {
    return creditLimit;
}

/**
 * @param creditLimit the creditLimit to set
 */
public void setCreditLimit(Double creditLimit) {
    this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
}

/**
 * @return the currentCredit
 */
public Double getCurrentCredit() {
    return currentCredit;
}

/**
 * @param currentCredit the currentCredit to set
 */
public void setCurrentCredit(Double currentCredit) {
    this.currentCredit = currentCredit;
}

/**
 * @return the salesOrders
 */
public List<SalesOrder> getSalesOrders() {
    return salesOrders;
}

/**
 * @param salesOrders the salesOrders to set
 */
public void setSalesOrders(List<SalesOrder> salesOrders) {
    this.salesOrders = salesOrders;
}



}
```

SalesOrder.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sales_order", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "orderNumber" }) })
public class SalesOrder extends BaseEntity {

@Column
private  String orderNumber;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private Customer customer;

@Column
private Double totalPrice;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="salesOrder",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<OrderLines> orderLines= new ArrayList<OrderLines>();

/**
 * @return the orderNumber
 */
public String getOrderNumber() {
    return orderNumber;
}

/**
 * @param orderNumber the orderNumber to set
 */
public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the customer
 */
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

/**
 * @param customer the customer to set
 */
public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

/**
 * @return the totalPrice
 */
public Double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

/**
 * @param totalPrice the totalPrice to set
 */
public void setTotalPrice(Double totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}

/**
 * @return the orderLines
 */
public List<OrderLines> getOrderLines() {
    return orderLines;
}

/**
 * @param orderLines the orderLines to set
 */
public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLines> orderLines) {
    this.orderLines = orderLines;
}   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please share your beans. 
Given your descriptionI expect you should have:

```
                @Entity
                @Table(name="CUSTOMER")
                public class Customer implements Serializable {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4505027246487844609L;

                    @Id
                    private String username;

                    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
                    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
                    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_USERNAME", nullable = false)
                    private List<SalesOrder> salesOrders;

                    }
```

The important part is:

```
                    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

The fetchtype is eager but could as well be lazy, there is no details about how you're fetching the data of the linked entity.
This should do the trick, thus if you remove the sales from the parent Customer, it will be deleted.

After you confirm that your bean is roughly structured like this, we can go on with analyzing your issue.

**UPDATE** if the bean are structured like this, than the reason for behaviour is clear..
when you fetch "Customer", you have the collection of relevant sales loaded...
Now.. you load in another object a sales linked to that customer, but object1 (customer) and object2 (sales) are completely separated now..
The result is that when you delete object2 you actually perform a delete, but then you save customer (where there is still a reference to the sale that you deleted in the list object), it will update/insert all the sales linked to the customer based on the customer bean.

Your situation is:
Customer with Sales1 and Sales2 fetched into Object1
Sales1 fetched into Object2
Delete Object2, it will delete sales1.. that won't change the content of Object1, that will still have a cusotmer linked with sales1 and sales2
save Object1, you will update customer (since it already exists), you will update sales2 (since it already exists) and insert sales1 (since you deleted it via the previous delete).
It will all be handled cleanly in the same transaction..

Now.. If you want to achieve your result, either you "reload" (do another findOne or whatever) the bean customer after the deletion of the related sales, or you work directly on the collection of sales included in the customer bean, and in case delete those object from the collection and saving the customer object when you are done, without involving a secondary object that is not linked to the customer that will just mess the whole flow..

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please see the domain classes.

Comment: answer updated explaining the behaviour.. given your bean structure and your code, what you are experiencing is the expected behaviour.. change slightly the code structure to achieve your desiderata as detailed in the update